# How to set up iAd Network in App Store ? and When?

Tags: iphone, app-store, iad

I am ready to submit my iAd enabled iphone application to the App Store. How can I setup the iAd Network in App Store & when? The iAd network agreement is signed. Should I click on on "Setup iAd Network" after filling metadata & screenshots OR after uploading my application binary ?

What information is required to setup the iAd network so that I keep it handy?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you have done with this. Can you please share the answer? I want to submit my updated version of the app. What should i do first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to upload application. Now, select the application and then you need to click on "iAd Network Settings" Button.

Comment: Do you mean I have to first upload my app binary to itunes connect then set up iAd Network. Is it so? Also can you tell me what information is required to setup the iAd network so that I keep it handy?